# Charger will only charge for a few seconds before needing replugging

Tags: charging

I use a clone charger wire for the iPhone. It looks very similar to an OEM version but is slightly different.

When I first started using it, upon closer inspection, I noticed that the metal connection end was a bit angled (when viewed sideways). I applied pressure to make the metal bit stick straight out.

First of all, I feel kinda stupid since it worked fine even though it was bent.

Now the thing only charges my phone for a few seconds before:

1. iPhone says this accesory may not be supported
2. iPhone acts as if I just pulled the charger from the port and stops charging

All while it's still plugged in and supposed to be charging.

What is wrong with the cable?

**Edit:** I accidentally dropped my iPhone while plugged in. The metal bit just bent like 30 degrees. I carefully bent it back into place.

Comment: What is wrong with the cable? I'd venture that paragraphs 2 and 8 should answer that question for you. Hopefully you haven't damaged the phone itself.

Comment: Charging, bent leads, plugging and unplugging.. You need to get a new wire and hope at this point, that is the only thing wrong.

Comment: @tubedogg the phone itself is fine.

Comment: @norcal i proably will. how are the 3rd party wires in comparison to OEM?

Comment: If you get one that's MFi (Made For iPhone/iPod/iPad) certified it should be fine. Beyond that you're on your own.

Comment: I was about to reply with what @tubedogg basically said. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

**More than likely, you broke the lightning connector solder joints on its PCB**

[image]

When you dropped your iPhone and bent your connector, you weakened the solder joints (yellow box).  When you bent it back, it probably broke the joint enough where it makes a very poor connection to no connection at all.

It's time for a new cable.